# How do I get cmd to recognize pip install?

Tags: python, pip

I have just started recently with Python, and have been trying to install modules for the first time. Unfortunately, whenever I try to install a downloaded .whl file, cmd just skips to the next line.

Here is what I see whenever I try to get pip to install a module.

[image]

[image]

Any help or information would be appreciated.

Comment: This question has been asked before; see [this link][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: What happens if you run `pip --version`? Try `py -mpip`