# Cmd does not recognize pip but python shell does

Tags: python, windows, pip

**Question:** How do you use pip when cmd does not recognize python or pip but python 3.7 shell recognizes pip?

**More Details:** I am a beginner coder (5-6 months in) and I installed python 3.7 a while back and to test for pip I typed in `import pip` in the shell with no error.  Unfortunately when I typed in `python -V` or `pip -V` into cmd It said python or pip was not recognized by the cmd. I don't know why this happened so I looked online and  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789330/how-do-i-get-cmd-to-recognize-pip-install)
about getting the cmd to recognize pip but it did not help very much.  When I tried to install pyaudio using `pip install pyaudio` in cmd it did not recognize pip once again. I do apologize for the poor wording on this question.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have u tried typing `pip3` instead of `pip` ?

also make sure your python is in your sytem PATH.

Answer (score 3):

Have tried to reinstall the python with enabling the Add PATH option??

This is happening due to path issue,  you can try this also.

goto python lib location via cmd after that try pip install {Module Nmae }

Comment: Is there another way besides reinstalling python to add it to the path?

Comment: You don't have to reinstall Python. Just modify the existing installation from its entry in the control panel's installed programs list. It should notify Explorer to update its environment variables, in which case new instances of shells (e.g. CMD, PowerShell) that are launched from Explorer will have the updated values of `PATH` and `PATHEXT`.